# jQuery's draggable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

When dragging an element can the draggable plugin prevent it from overflowing the other draggable elements? In other words, can it stop dragging the element when it reaches the edge of the other draggable element?

Answer (score 1):

You can contain the dragging within a parent element - if you contain all of the draggables within one element and set that as the containment, they will not be able to be dragged beyond that.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
```

(from http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Answer (score 0):

Exp:

```
$(element).draggable({ containment: 'body' });
```